# What does St. Augustine allude to when he writes in 'Confessions'?

Tags: predestination, reincarnation

In Book 1 of St. Augustine's 'Confessions', we read "Tell me, O God, I beg you; in your mercy tell me, pitiable creature that I am, did my infancy come after some other period of my existence which is now past ..."

Does this, and the passages which follow, allude to predestination or reincarnation?

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question (and I may have misunderstood the quotation of Augustine's words) but am I correct in thinking that (a) the foreknowledge of God and (b) the choosing of God's own in Christ are being - possibly - considered to be a kind of "pre-existence" ? {See [Pre-existence in Augustine's Seventh Letter](https://www.brepolsonline.net/doi/pdf/10.1484/J.REA.5.104165) }.